# Using woocommerce API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an online shop that uses woocommerce, wordpress.

We use a shared warehouse facilities of a firm that handles our products. They dont have a dedicated plugin for wordpress, but they sent me some API code that i have to inject in my site, in order to send them the order details to know what to goods to prepare.

They have sent me JS code

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/ImportOrders");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

var payload = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body> <ns1:ImportOrders> <ns1:livrare> &lt;CrosspointInboundMessage&gt; &lt;Order&gt; ... &lt;/Order&gt; &lt;/CrosspointInboundMessage&gt;</ns1:livrare></ns1:ImportOrders></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: payload
};

fetch("http://ws.qeops.ro/crosspointimportstandard.asmx?WSDL", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));`

fetch("http://ws.qeops.ro/health", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I need to use XML not json

Answer (score 0):

Please see a sample remote get request when an order is placed successfully.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'do_api_call' );

function do_api_call( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        $product_id  = $item[ 'product_id' ];
        $product     = new WC_Product( $product_id );


        $name    = $order->billing_first_name;
        $surname = $order->billing_last_name;
        $email   = $order->billing_email;
        $sku     = $product->get_sku();


        // API Callout to URL

        $url = 'http://ws.qeops.ro/health';

        $response = wp_remote_get( $url, array(
            'headers'    => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ),
            'method'     => 'GET',
            'redirect'   => 'follow',
            'timeout'    => 75,
            'sku'        => $sku,
            "name"       => $name,
            "surname"    => $surname,
            "email"      => $email,
        )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to send the payload in XML format not json